# Grocery CRUD : Auto-Insert corresponding value of a field after Dropdown has been selected

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, crud, grocery-crud

I have explored the new Grocery CRUD library & working on it easily.
I am now stuck on a problem.
I have a 2 tables with their fields-

**name_table** : id , Name , Item1, Price1

**items_table** : id, Item2, Price2

Now I can choose the field -(Item2) of **items_table** to be listed as a dropdown to **name_table** while adding the record using *set_relation* function. But how do i insert the value of **Price2 --> Price1** after the front end user has selected a specific dropdown.

Please check below Image Link & help me

[Visual Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yapCx.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
$crud->callback_field('field', array($this, 'field_callback'));
```

and in field_callback function:

```
function field_callback($value = '', $primary_key = null)
{

    $returner = "<select name='field' ></select>
                    <script type='text/javascript'>
                    -- JS AJAX SCRIPT
                    </script>";
    return $returner;
}
```

in this way you make a custom field with custom ajax in front end for your custom action